# the fitting out of [a trireme]: meaning

Tags: terminology

The sentence:

- *It belongs, also, to any lavish gifts made for the common good, such as a splendid donation for the benefits of all, or the fitting out of a trireme, or the giving of a banquet to the whole community.*

The explanation of "the fitting out of a trireme" is "a man, charged with an office by the state like the captaincy of a trireme, makes great expenditures in the execution of that office."

My question is:
Either 'fitting' or 'out of' has multiple definitions in Merriam Webster.
I am not sure which one exactly fits this sentence.
My guess of the meaning of 'fitting' is "something used in fitting up: accessory";
And the meaning of 'out of' is "used as a function word to indicate the center of an enterprise or activity"

Is that correct?  Thanks.

Comment: [OLD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/fit-out#:~:text=to%20supply%20someone%20or%20something,a%20stove%20and%20a%20sink.) [slightly modified] : << _fit somebody/something out/up (with something) [phrasal /multi-word verb]:
to supply someone or something with all the equipment, clothes, food, etc. they need_
synonym _equip_ ...
• to fit out a ship before a long voyage >>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not "fitting" versus "out of" ...
It is actually "fitting out [ of a trireme ]" ...

> fit out : Provide with (something) usually for a specific function

> trireme : Ancient Greek or Roman galley or warship having three tiers of oars on each side

Hence, this means "Providing a trireme [ with the requirements like new oars, weapons & ammunition ]" which is a common good benefiting all citizens against war ...

Comment: In this case, fitting out refers to the machinery of the vessel. It would be oars and weapons on a trireme, and possibly the cost of upkeep for the oarsmen. If you wanted to say "provide with a trireme", you would have to say something like "outfitting them with a trireme". Fitting out is what comes after the hull is built.

Comment: I have included that , @PhilSweet

Comment: Now I understand. Thanks, Prem and Phil, that helps a lot!